# how can I iterate over an array of element with webdriverio

Tags: jquery, angular, typescript, e2e-testing, webdriver-io

Can't iterate over the array element returned by wdio.
I want to be able to pass eny element from the array as a parameter to future functions and click the element that matches the condition.

Below code shows this error in the console "Can't call $ on element with selector "ng-drop-panel" because element wan't found.

```
let element = $$('ng-select');
for await (const item of element[0].$('ng-dropdown-panel').$('div').$$('div')[1].$$('div')) {
  if( await item.getText() == Field.CODE){
    item.click();
    break;
  }
}
```

Below code works fine but I wan't to be able to pass the element down as a parameter so I can avoid repetitive lines of code.

```
let element = $$('ng-select')[0];
for await (const itemof element.$('ng-dropdown-panel').$('div').$$('div')[1].$$('div')) {
  if( await item.getText() == Field.CODE){
    item.click();
    break;
  }
}
```

I have tried this but it doesn't work:

```
public async formFilling(){
  let element = $$('ng-select');
  await this.selectValueInDropDown(element[0].$('ng-dropdown-panel').$('div').$$('div')[1].$$('div'), "ADD");
}
public async selectValueInDropDown(dropDownSelector:any, dropDownValue: string){
  for await (const item of dropDownSelector) {
    if( await item.getText() == dropDownValue){
      item.click();
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of debugging I noticed that I didn't click the drop-down components therefore the inner HTML elements weren't been rendered yet. So just make sure to click the 'ng-select' for the options to show be shown.